# How to get second highest salary department wise?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose we have some employees in each department.we have total 3 departments . Below is the sample source table named 'employee'

```
emp dept_id salary
A    10     1000
B    10     2000
C    10     3000
D    20     7000
E    20     9000
F    20     8000
G    30     17000
H    30     15000
I    30     30000
j    30     30000
k    30     17000
```

Here may same salary is exist in same department.

I use Wamp-server which has mysql-5.7.23

And I want to like:

```
B    10     2000
F    20     8000
G    30     17000
```

Comment: may be your question is wrong because you mentioned "same salary is exist in same department " using that statement , you want output only related to department id 30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are several way to solve the problem. Following solution from my side and works fine.

```
SELECT *
From employee e2 
WHERE e2.salary = (SELECT distinct salary FROM employee where dept_id=e2.dept_id order by salary desc limit 1,1);
```

I need only second highest salary value with department wise which is the input array of next operation in my project. Finally I use

`SELECT e2.dept_id, max(e2.salary)
    From employee e2 
    WHERE e2.salary = (SELECT distinct salary FROM employee where dept_id=e2.dept_id order by salary desc limit 1,1)
group by e2.dept_id`

Comment: The `group by` is not required for this query (and in fact will cause it to fail on many MySQL installations due to a violation of sql mode `only_full_groupby`)

Comment: In this case without group by the result shown like:

B    10     2000
F    20     8000
G    30    17000
k     30    17000

so what do you think? @Nick

Comment: If the target is employee data, then you are right. But here I need only one data that the salary is 17000 which is the input of next operation as my project needs.

Comment: Then you could just change the query to `SELECT DISTINCT dept_id, salary` and you could still remove the `group by`. Otherwise you could keep the `group by` and change to `SELECT dept_id, MIN(salary)` (or `MAX`, since any values would be identical it doesn't matter)

Comment: You could simply join by emp instead of salary if you want exactly one row.